# HTML form does not pass data to php script

Tags: php, html, email

html markup for the form:

```
<form method="post" action="send_form_email.php">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Name: </label>
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Enter Name" name="name">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Email: </label>
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Message: </label>
                            <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Message" name="message"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" name="sended" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                    </form>
```

php file is as follows including 2 arrays to make the swop between variables:

```
<?php
    if(!isset($_POST['sended'])) {
        died("Йуху");
    }
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $mastermail="leshaber24@yandex.ru";
    $html = file_get_contents("./email-inlined.html");
// Массивы с заменой
    $search = array("#name#", "#email#", "#message#");
    $replace = array($name, $email, $message);
    $email_message = str_replace($search, $replace, $html); 
// create email headers
    $headers = 'From: '.$masteremail."\r\n".
    'Reply-To:'.$masteremail."\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
    $headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0'."\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";   
    mail($mastermail, "письмо из Сакуры", $html, $headers);  
    ?>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <h1>Thanks!</h1>
```

and the mail itself to be proceeded to the recepient:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Письмо с сайта</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <p>letter comes from <span>#name#</span></p>
        <p>email to reply <span>#email#</span></p>
        <p>message itself:<br><span>#message#</span></p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

the problem is that snippets are not changed with the data that comes from the form. Means that html data is not transmitted to php file.

Thanks!

Comment: You are using `$html` in your `mail()` call instead of `$email_message` (where you did all the replacing).

Comment: @ccKep but I did  $html = file_get_contents("./email-inlined.html");
means that now $html stores data from the file I wanna send, am I correct?

Comment: `$html = file_get_contents("./email-inlined.html");` means "get the contents of that file and store it in $html". After that, you're doing your `str_replace` on that and store those results in `$email_message`, hence: `$email_message` are the contents of your email with the placeholders replaced, `$html` is the original one. When you send the email you want to send the one with the replaced values ofcourse, hence `$email_message` instead of `$html`. Change `mail($mastermail, "письмо из Сакуры", $html, $headers);` to `mail($mastermail, "письмо из Сакуры", $email_message, $headers);`.

Comment: @ccKep got it, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies with what you are passing to the mail function. After storing the file_contents in $html, the replace you did is stored in $email_message but you still pass $html to the mail.

Change it to

```
mail($mastermail, "письмо из Сакуры", $email_message, $headers);
```